# How is it possible that I receive spam from myself?

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention

in my Gmail, occasionally I receive spam from my own email address, like:

```
from: me@gmail.com 
to: me@gmail.com
```

I am logged in to "Thunderbird" and "Chrome" on my PC, and a "Gmail" app on my Android.

Comment: The "From:" email address is not reliable and is easily spoofed. See my answer to a similar question [I received an email that appeared to be from my own mail-address](https://superuser.com/a/988994/337631)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

Comment: http://www.shortinfosec.net/2008/06/example-smtp-message-spoofing.html

Comment: its no different than sending a snail mail and writing a different originating address on the envelope.